# I've added the Template DB MySQL template to 2 servers in Zabbix 5.0.2. I can see the metric titles but no metric values

Tags: mysql, zabbix

I am seeing a unique issue where I have deployed "Template DB MySQL" from two different hosts but am unable to retrieve metric values.

I've created and tested the `"/etc/zabbix/zabbix_agentd.d/userparameter_mysql.conf"` file and I have created `"/var/lib/zabbix/.my.cnf"` file. I have also included the path to the file in `"/etc/zabbix/zabbix_agentd.conf"` file.
I am able to collect the metrics from the zabbiz_agentd CLI `zabbix_agentd -t Mysql.Server-Status`

`Mysql.Server-Status                           [t|{"Aborted_clients":"6","Aborted_connects":"1","Access_denied_errors":"0","Acl_column_grants":"0","Acl_database_grants":"0","Acl_function_grants":"0","Acl_procedure_grants":"0","Acl_package_spec_grants":"0","Acl_package_body_grants":"0","Acl_proxy_users":"0","Acl_role_grants":"0","Acl_roles":"0","Acl_table_grants":"0","Acl_users":"0","Aria_pagecache_blocks_not_flushed":"0","Aria_pagecache_blocks_unused":"15706","Aria_pagecache_blocks_used":"10","Aria_pagecache_read_requests":"27900","Aria_pagecache_reads":"25","Aria_pagecache_write_requests":"242","Aria_pagecache_writes":"242","Aria_transaction_log_syncs":"0","Binlog_commits":"0","Binlog_group_commits":"0","Binlog_group_commit_trigger_count":"0","Binlog_group_commit_trigger_lock_wait":"0","Binlog_group_commit_trigger_timeout":"0","Binlog_snapshot_file":"","Binlog_snapshot_position":"0","Binlog_bytes_written":"0","Binlog_cache_disk_use":"0","Binlog_cache_use":"0","Binlog_stmt_cache_disk_use":"0","Binlog_stmt_cache_use":"0","Busy_time":"0.000000","Bytes_received":"5490960","Bytes_sent":"28215386"--snip--`

In the agent log in debug 4 I see the following messages:

`820133:20201022:104034.062 Requested [mysql.version["localhost","3306"]] 820133:20201022:104034.062 Sending back [ZBX_NOTSUPPORTED: Item does not allow parameters.`
but no metrics are showing up in the front end. Does anybody know how this could be happening?

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: Key `Mysql.Server-Status` is not part of the [official mysql template](https://git.zabbix.com/projects/ZBX/repos/zabbix/browse/templates/db/mysql_agent?at=refs%2Fheads%2Frelease%2F5.0). Which template are you using?

Comment: Hi Iron Bishop. this is the UserParameter that I was using which I found in many tutorials: `UserParameter=Mysql.Server-Status, mysql --defaults-file=/var/lib/zabbix/.my.cnf --defaults-group-suffix=_monitoring -N -e "show global status" | jq -c '. | split("\n")[:-1] | map (split("\t") | {(.[0]) : .[1]} ) | add ' -R -s` and Im using the Template DB MySQL Agent 2

Answer (score 0):

OK, I figured out that the template macro {$MYSQL.USER} had auto corrected the first letter of the username to upper case. when I corrected that the metrics began flowing in.